# Enable Create a New Team Project under Collections in TFS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tds

When I am trying to create a New Team Project under collection in TFS 2015, there is no option for creating a new project. How do I enable that? Is there any step I am missing?

[image]

This is the [Document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project) I am referring to.

Comment: Are you a member of Project Collection Administrators or do you otherwise have Create New Project perms? Check your security settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using **TFS 2015 Update 2 or later**. Creating a team project from the web is a new feature in TFS 2015 Update 2 or later. In previous you must use Visual Studio to create Team Projects.
2. Make sure you are a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** Group, and you must have the **Create new projects** permission set to **Allow**.